# Lumen bloqueia apenas uma rota no CORS, todas as outras funcionam

Tags: laravel, cors, lumen

Tenho um sistema que estava a funcionar, mas de um momento para o outro deixou de funcionar. Dando erro "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" Etou a usar o Lumen com o pacote barryvdh/laravel-cors, todo o site funciona à excepção de um formulário publico que me dá esse erro.

A requisição é feita através de Angular:

```
insert (data: Object) {
    let observable = this.http.post(this.url, data, this.requestOptions.merge(new RequestOptions()));
    return this.toPromise(observable);
}
```

No Lumen recebo a requisição através da rota que reencaminha para esta função:

```
 public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, $this->rules ?? [], $this->messages ?? []);
    $result = $this->model->create($request->all());
    return response()->json($result);
}

insira o código aqui
```

Answer (score -2):

Consegui solucionar, era um problema na configuração do email no AppService provider, pois sempre que insere um registo é enviado um email e estava a retornar erro nessa configuração

```
    $this->app->configure('mail');
    $this->app->singleton('mailer', function(Application $app){
        $app->loadComponent('mail', MailServiceProvider::class, 'mailer');
    });
```

Alterei para :

```
    $this->app->configure('mail');
    $this->app->alias('mailer',Mailer::class);
```